# How can NULL and regular values be handled without using different prepared statements?

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

Consider this simple method:

```
public ResultSet getByOwnerId(final Connection connection, final Integer id) throws SQLException {
    PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = ?");
    statement.setObject(1, id);
    return statement.executeQuery();
}
```

The example method is supposed to select everything from some table where a column's value matches, which *should* be simple.
The ugly detail is that passing NULL for the id will result in an empty ResultSet, regardless how many rows there are in the DB because SQL defines NULL as not euqaling anyting, not even NULL.
The only way to select those rows I know of is using a different where clause:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn IS NULL
```

Unfortunately the only way to make the method work properly in all cases seems to be to have two entirely different execution pathes, one for the case where the id argument is null and one for regular values.

This is very ugly and when you have more than one column that can be nulled can get very messy quickly. How can one handle NULL and normal values with the same code path/statement?

Comment: I don't use JDBC, but in C# I generally set this up so that the `= ?` / `IS NULL` dynamically selected. The parameter, if any, is still bound via the prepared statement.

Comment: If you are using SQL Server, you can just do `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` and `field = NULL` will work.

Comment: Consider Hibernate or JPA. It'll save you from JDBC boilerplate.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this, but the way to send nulls to preparedStatements is to use the setNull() option

```
   PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE MyColumn = ?");
    if ( id == null)
       statement.setNull(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
    else    
      statement.setObject(1, id);
    return statement.executeQuery();
```

**EDIT** : Thanks for the responses @Gabe and @Vache. It does not look like there is an easy way to do this other than taking a more longwinded approach to dynamically create the preparedstatment.

Something like this should work --

```
String sql = " SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE " + (id==null)?"MyColumn is null":"MyColumn = ?" ;
       PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        if ( id != null)
          statement.setObject(1, id);
        return statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: In ANSI SQL, `MyColumn = NULL` will never be true, even when `MyColumn` has the `NULL` value.

Comment: It will set an "SQL null", but the `MyColumn = NULL` will still return no results. `setNull` is mostly used for insertion queries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a query like this:

```
select * from MyTable where 
  case when ?1 is null then MyColumn is null else MyColumn = ?1
```

But it *reuses* the same parameter, so I don't know whether the syntax I've proposed (?1) will work.